# Weaving elements into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem statement:

> Modify a given list such that one specific element is "weaved" into that list.
>
> Examples if the element is `'module'`:
>
> - `[]` remains `[]`
> - `['a']` remains `['a']`
> - `['a', 'b']` becomes `['a', 'module', 'b']`
> - `['a', 'b', 'c']` becomes `['a', 'module', 'b', 'module', 'c']`

I solved it using the following code in Python 3.4:

```
@staticmethod
def __weave_element_into_list(element, values: list) -> list:
    """
    Weaves an element into a given list.

    Examples if the element is 'module':
     - Input [] remains [].
     - Input ['a'] remains ['a'].
     - Input ['a', 'b'] becomes ['a', 'module', 'b'].
     - Input ['a', 'b', 'c'] becomes ['a', 'module', 'b', 'module', 'c'].
     - etc.

    :param element: The element to weave into the list
    :param values:  The original list
    :return:    The list with element weaved into it.
    """
    copy_list = list(values)
    if len(copy_list) <= 1:
        return copy_list
    i = 1
    while i < len(copy_list):
        copy_list.insert(i, element)
        i += 2
    return copy_list
```

Is there a better (more Pythonic?) solution to it and is "weaving" the correct operation here?

Comment: Where's the rest of the class? What context is this used in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function could be replaced with this line:

```
return list(chain.from_iterable(zip(values, [element] * len(values))))[:-1]
```

Essentially,
zipping `values` with another list of the same size containing `element` in all values, flattening the zip, and chopping off the end.

About your original implementation, instead of this:

> ```
> if len(copy_list) <= 1:
>     return copy_list
> ```

This is more Pythonic:

```
if not copy_list:
    return copy_list
```

I'm also wondering if this needs to be a `@staticmethod`.
Since it's a pure function, I'd just call it weave.
Here's the complete implementation with doctests:

```
from itertools import chain


def weave(element, values: list) -> list:
    """
    >>> weave('module', [])
    []
    >>> weave('module', ['a'])
    ['a']
    >>> weave('module', ['a', 'b'])
    ['a', 'module', 'b']
    >>> weave('module', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    ['a', 'module', 'b', 'module', 'c']

    :param element: The element to weave into the list
    :param values: The original list
    :return: The list with element weaved into it.
    """
    return list(chain.from_iterable(zip(values, [element] * len(values))))[:-1]
```

I see @jonrsharpe beat me to the doctests.
To add something new,
another way to run doctests:

```
python -m doctest yourfile.py
```

#### Update

Originally I proposed this one-liner:

```
return sum(zip(values, [element] * len(values)), ())[:-1]
```

But that turns out to be a [bad idea](https://mathieularose.com/how-not-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python/).
This [other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/408281/641955) is also illuminating.

Comment: Using `sum(lst, ())` instead of `flatten` borders on obfuscation

Comment: @Caridorc you're absolutely right, thanks for picking on it. I updated my post with a different solution, and some related links at the bottom.

Comment: Consider `zip_longest(values, repeat(element, max(len(values) - 1, 0)))` — this avoids the unnecessary allocation of the list of elements, and it avoids the unnecessary copy due to the `[:-1]`.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you can make the examples into [`doctest`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html), so that you can actually run them to check the function works:

```
class Class:  # or whatever it's called

    @staticmethod
    def __weave_element_into_list(element, values: list) -> list:
        """
        Weaves an element into a given list.

        Examples:

            >>> Class._Class__weave_element_into_list('module', [])
            []
            >>> Class._Class__weave_element_into_list('module', ['a'])
            ['a']
            >>> Class._Class__weave_element_into_list('module', ['a', 'b'])
            ['a', 'module', 'b']
            >>> Class._Class__weave_element_into_list('module', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
            ['a', 'module', 'b', 'module', 'c']

        :param element: The element to weave into the list
        :param values: The original list
        :return: The list with element weaved into it.
        """
        copy_list = list(values)
        if len(copy_list) <= 1:
            return copy_list
        i = 1
        while i < len(copy_list):
            copy_list.insert(i, element)
            i += 2
        return copy_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

---

Now, note how awkward it is to have to call `Class._Class__weave_element_into_list`, due to the *"name mangling"* invoked by the leading double underscore in the method name. Per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), this should only be used:

> To avoid name clashes with subclasses

instead if you want the method to be considered 'private':

> Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables.

Without seeing the rest of your code it's also hard to say why you've made this a method, rather than just a standalone function.

---

Your `weave` operation works exactly like [the `join` method for `str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> ' module '.join('')
''
>>> ' module '.join('a')
'a'
>>> ' module '.join('ab')
'a module b'
>>> ' module '.join('abc')
'a module b module c'
```

so perhaps that would be a better term to adopt for it.

Comment: I don't understand why you are bothering with a class at all... in Python, it is perfectly fine for a function to just be a function.

Comment: @codesparkle that's a better comment for the OP than for me!

Answer (score 7):

Haskell calls this function [`intersperse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse).

In Python, loops where you manually increment the index tend to be awkward.  I propose the following solution:

```
import itertools

def intersperse(element, iterable):
    def alternation():
        for item in iterable:
            yield element
            yield item
    return list(itertools.islice(alternation(), 1, None))
```

[`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is just a handy way to drop the first element of the result.  You could also write it this way without `itertools`:

```
def intersperse(element, iterable):
    def alternation():
        for item in iterable:
            yield element
            yield item
    result = alternation()
    next(result, None)
    return list(result)
```

---

Your `__weave_element_into_list()` has a scalability problem: inserting elements into the middle of a list requires a lot of work to shift all subsequent items.  The `weave()` function proposed in Rev 2 of @janos's answer involved even more copying, since tuples are immutable; the revision in Rev 3 has *much* better performance characteristics.

Benchmark:

```
import timeit

functions = ('intersperse', 'weave2', 'weave3', '__weave_element_into_list')
print('length  ' + ' '.join('{:12s}'.format(f) for f in functions))
for length in [0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
    print('{0:6d}  '.format(length) +
          ' '.join('{: >3.10f}'.format(
              timeit.timeit("f('alligator', range({}))".format(length),
                            setup="from __main__ import {} as f".format(f),
                            number=100)) for f in functions))
```

Result:

```
length  intersperse  weave2       weave3       __weave_element_into_list
     0  0.0002215109 0.0001669568 0.0002566511 0.0000781892
     1  0.0002748552 0.0002680188 0.0003487850 0.0001115086
    10  0.0003961320 0.0003857883 0.0004681549 0.0005727541
   100  0.0019150120 0.0054596220 0.0015901779 0.0048249909
  1000  0.0183790531 0.3636222179 0.0120774899 0.0711144698
 10000  0.1597181219 41.7615168821 0.1375140301 3.6747105517
```